# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null (querySelector)

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

`addEventListener` works perfectly fine on a single id (menu)... Is there a restriction that I can't use it on querySelector?

(Yes, JavaScript is at the bottom of the HTML document)

Any help will be appreciated.

https://plnkr.co/edit/AIAOZk40ssoofpvrt9dm?p=preview

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var area = document.querySelector("#menu + #envelope + #links");

menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", addHref);
area.addEventListener("mouseleave", remHref);

menu.addEventListener("click", addHref);
document.addEventListener("click", function (){
    if (this != area){
        remHref();
    }
});

function remHref (){
    document.getElementById("google").removeAttribute("href");
    document.getElementById("mysite").removeAttribute("href");
}

function addHref (){
    setTimeout(activate, 2500);
}

function activate (){
    document.getElementById("google").setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com");
    document.getElementById("mysite").setAttribute("href", "https://www.mywebsite.com");
}
```

```
    <div id="menu">Click here to browse the internet.
        <div id="envelope">
            <div id="links" >
                <div><a ><img id="google" src="https://seomofo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" /></a></div>
                <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
                <div><a ><img id="mysite" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/wwf-logo-horizontal-world-wildlife-foundation-logo-shirt-11563219164hg5hfcveei.png"/></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
#menu{
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    padding-top: 5vh;
}

#menu:hover{
    color: red;
}

#envelope{
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
}

#links{
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    background-color: pink;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}


#google{
    margin-top: -1vh;
    width: 150px;
}

#mysite{
    padding-left: 5%;
    margin-top: -1vh;
    width: 150px;
}

#menu:hover #envelope{
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#menu:focus #envelope{
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#menu:hover #links{
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#menu:focus #links{
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: `"#menu + #envelope + #links"` is looking for `<xxx id="menu"></xxx><xxx id="envelope"></xxx><xxx id="links"></xxx>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var area = document.querySelector("#menu + #envelope + #links");
```

for:

```
var area = document.querySelector("#menu #envelope #links");
```

As your html is:

```
<div id="menu">Click here to browse the internet.
   <div id="envelope">
      <div id="links" >
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The `element+element selector` (Adjacent Sibling Selector) is used to select elements that are placed immediately after (**not inside**) the first specified element. You need the Descendant Selector or the Child Selector.

Have a look at the [w3cschools CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

Or, in this case and as epascarello says, you can just use:

```
var area = document.querySelector("#links");
```

as the ids must be unique if the document validates.

Comment: or just "#links" since ids have to be singular.

Comment: Yep, as it's an id it should be unique if the document is well formed

Answer (score 1):

i've edited your plunk to fit the 2 small mistake you've made.

The first mistake was to include the script in the  tag.
i've put in before the closing  tag

Also, as mentionned @jeprubio you need to remove the '+' from the querySelector() call.

Here is the edited plunk

https://plnkr.co/edit/sB7r0MguCN3KvhdHvB4i

code

// Code goes here

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var area = document.querySelector("#menu #envelope #links");

menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", addHref);
area.addEventListener("mouseleave", remHref);

menu.addEventListener("click", addHref);
document.addEventListener("click", function (){
    if (this != area){
        remHref();
    } 
});

function remHref (){
    document.getElementById("google").removeAttribute("href");
    document.getElementById("mysite").removeAttribute("href");
}

function addHref (){
    setTimeout(activate, 2500);
}

function activate (){
    document.getElementById("google").setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com");
    document.getElementById("mysite").setAttribute("href", "https://www.mywebsite.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine you need just to :

- Place your script before closing tag `</body>`.
- Correct querySelector fo element area from `"#menu + #envelope + #links"` to `"#menu  #envelope  #links"`

Example :

```js
// Code goes here


var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var area = document.querySelector("#menu #envelope #links");

menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", addHref);
area.addEventListener("mouseleave", remHref);

menu.addEventListener("click", addHref);
document.addEventListener("click", function (){
 if (this != area){
  remHref();
 }
});

function remHref (){
 document.getElementById("google").removeAttribute("href");
 document.getElementById("mysite").removeAttribute("href");
}

function addHref (){
 setTimeout(activate, 2500);
}


function activate (){
 document.getElementById("google").setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com");
 document.getElementById("mysite").setAttribute("href", "https://www.mywebsite.com");
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#menu{
 height: 10vh;
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 1s ease-out;
 padding-top: 5vh;
}

#menu:hover{
 color: red;
}

#envelope{
 height: 0;
 display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: blue;
 min-width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 content: "";
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
}

#links{
 height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 display: flex;
 background-color: pink;
 justify-content: center;
 z-index: 2;
 min-width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 1s ease-in;
}


#google{
 margin-top: -1vh;
 width: 150px;
}

#mysite{
 padding-left: 5%;
 margin-top: -1vh;
 width: 150px;
}

#menu:hover #envelope{
 height: 100px;
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}

#menu:focus #envelope{
 height: 100px;
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}

#menu:hover #links{
 opacity: 1;
 height: 300px;
 visibility: visible;
}

#menu:focus #links{
 opacity: 1;
 height: 300px;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">Click here to browse the internet.1
        <div id="envelope">
            <div id="links">
                <div>
                    <a><img id="google" src="https://seomofo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
                <div>
                    <a><img id="mysite" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/wwf-logo-horizontal-world-wildlife-foundation-logo-shirt-11563219164hg5hfcveei.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Javascript in window.onload()

```
window.onload=function() {
   /*your code here*
   /*var date = document.getElementById("date");
   /*alert(date);
}
```

It looks like the browser is executing your JavaScript before it has "executed your HTML"/made the page, so those HTML elements/DOM nodes don't exist yet.  This introduces a delay until the HTML is loaded, so that the nodes exist (not null) before JavaScript tries to attach methods to them. (And what jprubio said below about your selector.)